# Htaccess redirect to page and change the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to `www.domain.com/store/bg/user/login` but to rename the url to `www.domain.com/storeadmin/bg/user/login` without affect the rendered view. What I am doing to redirect ot the login page on this kind of url `www.domain.com/storeadmin` is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?storeadmin/([a-z]{2})/user/login/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/%1/user/login [NC,R=301,L]
```

and it works fine. What I tried to rename the url after the redirect is over is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?storeadmin/([a-z]{2})/user/login/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/%1/user/login [NC,R=301,N] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /storeadmin/%1/user/login [L]
```

Added `N` flag to continue to the next rule and after that `L` to stop the other rules. Guess this is not the right way because what i get is `Internal Server Error`. Can you give me advice, how to accomplish my task? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve after initial successful redirect (what does "rename URL" mean?).

Comment: In the first example it goes to `www.domain.com/store/bg/user/login`. "Rename the url" means to stay on the same page with the same view but only renames the url in the address bar - 
 `www.domain.com/storeadmin/bg/user/login` :)

Comment: But isn't that what the user initially entered?

Comment: The user enters `www.domain.com/storeadmin` it goes to `www.domain.com/store/bg/user/login` and after the redirect I want to rewrite the url like `www.domain.com/storeadmin/bg/user/login`. I am familiar with them urls, so I am sorry if the question is stupid  or maybe what I want is impossible :/

Comment: It is not stupid if there is a use case :). But if I see correctly, you want to redirect twice only to bring user back to url that he initially entered?

Comment: I want to redirect him to the admin if he enters `/storeadmin` but the login form is one for both them front and admin. What I am doing in the controller/action is searching in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for `/storeadmin` and if it is there, then I am redirecting it to the admin.The problem occures because in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  ..  `/storeadmin` never shows. It is always `/store` because of the redirect in the `.htaccess`. I am not sure if I explained it well and I am pretty sure there is an easier solution, but I am an stubborn :D Appreciate that your trying to help me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164263/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-toma-tomov).